# Getting email provider from email address

Tags: email, smtp

I'm trying to get the email provider (ex: gmail,outlook,yahoo) from any email address so that i can use specific smtp settings to avoid my messages being listed as spam.

My current approach is parsing the mail server potion of the email address and using that as the identifier but email providers have multiple mail servers (ex: outlook has outlook.com but also live.ca).

Any suggestions of a simple approach to identifying the mail provider? If there is any method using PHP that would be especially desirable. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map for mapping the mail domain name (that you obtain after parsing the e-mail address) to the mail provider:

```
$providerMap = array(
    "gmail" => "Gmail"
    "outlook" => "Outlook"
    "live" => "Outlook"
    # etc...
);
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
$providerDomain = getDomain($emailAddress); // assuming getDomain() is the function that parses an email address and returns 

echo "The provider is: $providerMap[$providerDomain]"
```

P.S.: You may want to think about how to handle the case where the email address domain name doesn't match any provider. You can:

- Throw an exception/display an error message
- Add a functionality allowing an authorised user to add a new provider (i.e. for adding a new entry in the map)
- ...